# Is $H$ the Commutator Subgroup of $G$ if $H\neq \{1\}, H\leq G$ and $[H, G] = [H, H]$?

Tags: group-theory, alternative-proof

I'm working on the following problem obtained when trying to prove in a different way that the alternating group $A_n$ is the commutator subgroup of the symmetric group $S_n$ if $n\geq 5$.

(Again, I have proved the original problem, and the following is just part of a different attempt)

Gievn a group $G$ and a nontrivial subgroup $H\leq G$, prove or disprove that if $[H, G] = [H, H]$, then $H$ is, or contains, the commutator subgroup of $G$.

Here $[A, B]=<[a, b] | a\in A, b\in B>$ denotes the group generated by commutators of elements from $A$ and from $B$ ($A, B$ are subgroups of a certain group).

Any idea is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. If $H = Z(G)$ is the center then $[H, G] = [H, H] = e$ but $Z(G)$ need not be or contain the commutator subgroup.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Well, there is one more question which looks kind of trivial but I'm not quite sure about. If $H, D, M, N$ are subgroups of a certain group, and $H\leq D, M\leq N$, is it true that $[H, M]\leq [D, N]$?

Comment: @Liebster: Yes, of course. Every commutator of the form $[h, m], h \in H, m \in M$ is by hypothesis also a commutator of the form $[d, n], d \in D, n \in N$.